# Setting surefire and failsafe environment variables from a file

Tags: maven

I have a list of environmental variables, required by various Java classes. (I realize Maven favors Java system properties over environment variables; but, with 12-factor approaches, combined with Spring Java-based config, I need 
 environment variables).

I have a file (Websphere server.env) listing all the environment variables, and the RHS of each is set from Maven variables, depending on what profile is used in the build (using resource plugin filtering).

I also want the same list of variables set for Surefire and for Failsafe. I can easily reformat the file into some other format, but those plugins do not accept a file for environment variables. Rather, each variable must be listed in the POM itself.

That means listing the same variable in multiple places. I can do that if there's no better option, but that's my question:  is there a better option ?

Added:
Steve C. pointed me to [Properties Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/). Trying to figure out how I'd use that, I come up with this:

- Either... Define Maven properties as needed and write them to server.env
- Or... Define server.env and read it in as Maven properties

That seems to still leave me with Surefire and Failsafe, since I will have to list each of them, creating an Environment variable for each Maven property. Or, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Properties Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/)

It was designed to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. After reading that, I think is solves part of my problem, but maybe I'm not thinking about right. Have updated my question with a further question.